# Using IF Formula to get data from another Cell

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I am just trying to use the IF formula:

```
  COLUMN A       COLUMN B       COLUMN C
                 Cats           NULL
                 Dogs           Monkeys
                 Kittens        NULL
```

So, I want to do this while having selected A1:

```
  =IF(C1='NULL',B1,C1)
```

So, the end result for A1 would show me "Cats" because C1 is NULL

But A2 would show me Monkeys because C2 is NOT Null.

I get an error when I use this formula AS IS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double instead of single quotations marks

i.e. `=IF(C1="NULL",B1,C1)`

**References**
[IF - Google Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)